# Can't see Windows 8 default apps

Tags: windows-8, 64-bit, modern-ui

As seen in the image below, I could not even access Settings because everything could not be seen. For some other apps like Weather, I could somehow see it but some of the text looks really blurred.

Specifications:

- Asus A45V laptop
- Intel i7-3630QM CPU
- Intel HD 4000 Graphics
- nVidia GeForce GT 645M

[image]

Comment: How about some details? like what graphics hardware and pc you are using. Also the image appears to be just a thumbnail.

Comment: Hope my edits do help...

Comment: never tried that. but what settings am I supposed to change?

Comment: I could access both graphic card's settings on the monitors, profiles, orientation though

Comment: I found more about my PC's specs:
OS Name Microsoft Windows 8
Version 6.2.9200 Build 9200
Other OS Description  Not Available
OS Manufacturer Microsoft Corporation
System Name AARON
System Manufacturer ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
System Model K45VS
System Type x64-based PC
System SKU ASUS-NotebookSKU
Processor Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3630QM CPU @ 2.40GHz, 2401 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s)
BIOS Version/Date American Megatrends Inc. 223, 9/26/2012
SMBIOS Version 2.7
Embedded Controller Version 255.255
BIOS Mode UEFI
BaseBoard Manufacturer ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.

Comment: BaseBoard Model Not Available
BaseBoard Name Base Board
Platform Role Mobile
Secure Boot State On
PCR7 Configuration Binding Not Possible
Windows Directory C:\Windows
System Directory C:\Windows\system32
Boot Device \Device\HarddiskVolume1
Locale United States
Hardware Abstraction Layer Version = "6.2.9200.16384"
User Name Aaron\AUBUNTU
Time Zone China Standard Time
Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 8.00 GB
Total Physical Memory 7.88 GB
Available Physical Memory 6.32 GB
Total Virtual Memory 12.4 GB
Available Virtual Memory 8.01 GB
Page File Space 4.50 GB
Page File C:\pagefile.sys